# How does modernizr.js communicate with HTML5 files?

Tags: html, css, cordova, modernizr

I want to use modernizr.js with my website. 
How does it work?
How does it communicate with other js files?
How can I use it?

Does it work in Mobile Application Development with PhoneGap?

Comment: have you seen http://modernizr.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Modernizr runs quickly on page load to detect features; it then
>   creates a JavaScript object with the results, and adds classes to the
>   html element for you to key your CSS on. Modernizr supports dozens of
>   tests, and optionally includes YepNope.js for conditional loading of
>   external .js and .css resources.

Yes, it does work with phonegap.  Usually what modernizr does is just check if the "browser" has teh specific property and apply a class to the html tag. so you can create styles for browsers that support and browsers that dont support the feature in question.

eg

```
cssmasks .icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffcc33;
    display: inline-block;
}
.no-cssmasks .icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('http://i.cubeupload.com/VvBVjp.png'); 
}
.cssmasks .icon-note{
    -webkit-mask-image: url('http://i.cubeupload.com/VvBVjp.png'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful reply.It shows that the browser supports the tag or not. But will it add the solution too?

Comment: No, it wont add the solution. It's not going to make the browser compatible as the lack of information in some articles might suggest.  It simply verifies if the browser can do something and let your css know so you can program a special case if that feature is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know, it mostly use for HTML5 or CSS3 in non-supporting browsers.

Modernizr is a small JavaScript library that detects the availability of native implementations for next-generation web technologies, i.e. features that stem from the HTML5 and CSS3 specifications. Many of these features are already implemented in at least one major browser (most of them in two or more), and what Modernizr does is, very simply, tell you whether the current browser has this feature natively implemented or not.

Check out this link - http://modernizr.com/docs/#whatis